# How to remove duplicates from a dataframe column with more than one value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

The data:

[image: The data]

I want to remove duplicates from "Borough" without deleting the rows, I only need only one value for each

```
g2 = dfff.groupby(['Postcode'])["Borough"].agg( ','.join)
g3 = dfff.groupby(['Postcode'])["Neighbourhood"].agg( ','.join)
df2=pd.DataFrame(g2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(g3)
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, on='Postcode')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].  How can you expect anyone to help you if you aren't willing to put any effort into even asking a question?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicate()`? This should do for your case. Or explain in detail what output you are expecting.

Comment: i tried this but its delete the whole rows , i need the rows that have ("Borough" : newyork , newyork ) to have just one value ( one place) not the two of them

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Comment: Dont have the answer , to type it , dont need to copy all the dataframe  its not necessary , i just need the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "data": ['scarborough, scarborough, scarborough', 'london,london', 'north york, north york', 'test,test']
})

# logic
def custom_dedup(s):
    return [*set([_.strip() for _ in s.split(',')])][0]

df['data'].apply(custom_dedup)
```

How it works

1. `split()`: split the string on commas, which yields a list
2. `strip()`: remove outer spaces from the each string in the list
3. `set()`: get the unique elements from that list
4. `...[0]`: we assume there's only one element per set, so take the first element

Input:

```
    data
0   scarborough, scarborough, scarborough
1   london,london
2   north york, north york
3   test,test
```

Output:

```
0    scarborough
1         london
2     north york
3           test
```